# Running into a infinite number when doing a json_encode in php

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have run into a very strange problem with json_encode in php.

```
<?php 

// this is just example data, please pretend this is coming 
//  out of a database query in laravel  (DB::SELECT("sql query here"))
$arrOfClasses = [];
$arrOfClasses[] = (object) array(   'name'=>'Joe Schmo',
                                    'id'  => '315e321268',
                                    'custNum' => '123');

$arrOfClasses[] = (object) array(   'name'=>'Jill Jones',
                                    'id'  => '123123123',
                                    'custNum' => '456');


echo "<pre>";

print_r($arrOfClasses);

$tmpArr = [];
foreach ($arrOfClasses as $c) {

    // I broke the encode and decode parts of this out 
    //   in order to trap where the error is ocurring

    echo "Processing: " . $c->name . "<br>";
    $tmp = json_encode($c, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);  // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS HAPPENING

    // it is seeing the id of the first user as a infinite number

    $tmpReturn = json_last_error_msg();
    echo $tmpReturn . "<hr>";

    $tmp2 = json_decode($tmp,true);
    $tmpArr[] = $tmp2;
}

print_r($tmpArr);
```

This is the output I get from this code snippet:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Joe Schmo
            [id] => 315e321268
            [custNum] => 123
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Jill Jones
            [id] => 123123123
            [custNum] => 456
        )

)
Processing: Joe Schmo
Inf and NaN cannot be JSON encodedProcessing: Jill Jones
No errorArray
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Jill Jones
            [id] => 123123123
            [custNum] => 456
        )

)
```

The problem seems to be with the ID of Joe Schmo in my sample data.  When it runs thru the json_encode function, it tries to convert this to a number because of the JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK.  In my actual application which is a Laravel backend API for a JS frontend, I need to return numbers as numbers, and strings as strings, so I need to have that JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK in there.

PLEASE NOTE:  If I take the JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK out in the example code I posted, it seems to be working fine.  However, since Laravel 4.2 is using a "Response::json()" to output the code to the browser, I believe it is running into the same problem internally.

I do not know how to get around this problem.  The temporary fix that I came up with looks like this:

```
        foreach ($results[$key] as $key2=>$val2) {
            if (is_numeric($val2)) {
                if (is_infinite($val2)) {
                    $results[$key]->$key2 = "'" . $val2 . "'";
                }
            }
        }
```

However, this can cause problems as some customers use this particular endpoint, and won't know to remove the single quotes that I bracketed the value that json_encode is seeing as an infinite number.

I'm still researching, but if anyone can give me a hand with resolving this, I would be most appreciative.

Wade

Comment: Do you have control over the format of the IDs?

Comment: No, these id's are entered by various customers. This is an edge case for sure, but I need to support this type of data.

Comment: Can you encode AND decode the IDs? That is, do you have access to the pre-json-encoded data and the post-json-encode data?

Comment: Does data have the same predefined structure or it can vary?

Comment: Are edge cases legitimate hexadecimal numbers or could there be a letter e.g. "q" in the ID?

Comment: Whenever I try the json_encode on that particular data, the json error that I showed in the output comes up.  I actually store these values in the database encrypted in AES format.  Everything works fine in the backend until I try and convert the array of objects to a standard array.  Then it balks that that particular bit of data because it thinks it is an infinite number.

Comment: The data in these fields can be anything as they are setup by the customer.

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64695

apparently there is a bug

Comment: I can run you code with no problem

Comment: Can you add keys to each array before json encoding?

Comment: 5.5.36 is the version of PHP we are running.  Looks like we might need to change our version of PHP.

Comment: and 5.5.20 on the servers

Comment: Patrick Moore - Thank you for the link.  I didn't find that after all morning of searching.  There was a bug report at the very end of that.

Comment: cmorrissey - What version of php are you running?